# Unassigned reference exception in C# Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

1. I have a player class where I am updating a Transform named `Target` and Target belongs to `Projectile` class.

Here is what I did and by this it works just fine:

```
_pro.Target.transform.position = new Vector3(posi.x, posi.y, posi.z);  //value gets assigned to Target here
Instantiate (bulletprefab, position, Quaternion.identity);  //projectile is attached to bulletprefab so projectile gets called from here
```

Now, in projectile, on trying to access `Target.transform.position`, it gives UnassignedReferenceException : The variable 'Target' of projectile has not been assigned yet.

I successfully assigned value to `Target` in player class, How do I access the same value in projectile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is that you are trying to update the value of a variable before the object that contains that variable is instantiated.

Since your `Projectile` class has a reference to the target, first you need a reference to the `Projectile` class instance.

So instantiate your object and then find the `Projectile` class.

```
GameObject g = Instantiate (bulletprefab, position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
Projectile p = g.GetComponent<Projectile>();
```

Then use your new reference to projectile to assign the value to target.

```
p.SetTarget(target.transform.position);
```

---

You could also use [SendMessage](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.SendMessage.html) to solve the same problem.

```
GameObject g = Instantiate (bulletprefab, position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
g.SendMessage("SetTarget", target.transform.position);
```

In both cases I assume you have a function named `SetTarget` that allows you to set the target in the `Projectile` class.

Comment: I would like to make it clear that Target is originally declared in projectile class. I used reference to projectile to update Target transform.In Update Method of player, I am updating Target and want to get the same updated position on using Target.transform.position, so do I really need to do this g.GetComponent<PROJECTILE> again? since in player class, I already used GetComponent<projectile> to get acceSs to TARGET and so as to update in Update method of player class

Comment: The value of Target.tranform needs to be updated just before instantiating the bulletprefab, so I was bound to use Update method of Player class. Now, I just need to know  away to fetch those updated values in projectile class, please?

Comment: I believe I wanted to do pass by reference, and what is happening above is pass by value, right?

Comment: Yes, it is pass by value. How is it possible that you update a variable of an object before it is instantiated? Also, what do you mean by this: "I am updating Target and want to get the same updated position on using Target.transform.position"

Comment: Okay, so here is what I meant:--> Target is originally declared in projectile, but since projectile is the script attached to bulletprefab,(for some reason), I always want the position of Target 'at the time' of instantiation of feedback, so I am updating position of Target in update method of player , having done that, I want this updated position of Target to use in the projectile script. So, updating the value in player script(Target is moving continuously), is done, Now, I just need a way to update Target.transform in the projectile script.

Comment: When you say this line `_pro.Target.transform.position = new Vector3(posi.x, posi.y, posi.z);` works, that is impossible. You are trying to update the value of a `GameObject` that doesn't exist yet, that is why when you try to check the value of Target inside the projectile it tells you that it doesn't point to anything.